# How are laravel queues named on windows server?

Tags: laravel

I have my local development server setup on Laragon, Windows, and I cannot change it.

On my Linux development server I simply need to run `ps faux | grep queue:work` to see if queues are running, but on Windows I'm stuck.

I can run `tasklist 2>NUL /V` but then I'm not able to understand which one is the process I need to look for; my quess is that it is `php.exe` but I'm not sure about it.

EDIT: I need to retrieve informations from php code, as of now I'm running `exec("tasklist 2>NUL /V", $task_list);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell which seems to be much more powerful than the standard windows' cmd.exe.

According to docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-6

it should be fairly easy to get many different characteristics of the processes.

Comment: how can I call it from php code? Right now I'm doing `exec("tasklist 2>NUL /V", $task_list);`

Comment: You can use built-in php functions maybe? I didn't know you run it from code, not console: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.win32-ps-list-procs.php

Comment: I tried `exec("wmic process list")` but I still can't get the names properly. Maybe there's a way to define a name when calling a command in Laravel?

Comment: it's easier to just intercept a proccess id.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php#115702

Permission issue, maybe you can't see the queue processes running because they belong to the 'system account'.

Comment: I think I can see all processes, but the names are "php.exe"

Comment: I see. In that case, I think it's a tasklist limitation. I tried googling around but didn't hit anything good related to tasklist. I've found about pslist, maybe that's your guy.